# Call WCF with windows authentication from SWAGGER-UI

Tags: wcf, rest, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

I have a WCF REST service that uses windows authentication here is the configuration:

```
   <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="web_authenticate_binding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

I am trying to use SWAGGER-UI (and SWAGGER Editor) to invoke this REST service  but when I invoke the service I get **401 Unauthorized** as expected, because I am not sending my windows credentials.

How can I send my windows credentials to the SWAGGER-UI or give it as parameter so everyone can pass its own credentials?

Answer (score 1):

If you want that someone passes his own credentials, you will need to change the `clientCredentialType`. This reference may help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733836(v=vs.110).aspx.

The `Basic` authentication type is probably the simplest one, but it depends if it is suitable for you.